# Confused by BluetoothGattServerCallback#onCharacteristicWriteRequest

Tags: android

Got confused by the Android [BluetoothGattServerCallback#onCharacteristicWriteRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback) method.

1. For the parameter `preparedWrite`, I thought it would be my responsibility to implement the write operation, how does the callback know when I should queue the message?
2. The documentation says `An application must call BluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(BluetoothDevice, int, int, int, byte[]) to complete the request.`, what if `responseNeeded` is false?
3. Calling `BluetoothGattServer#sendResponse(BluetoothDevice, int, int, int, byte[])` seems always returns the value in the request, no matter what I set to `value`. Is it expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `preparedWrite` is used to support long writes (greater than the MTU).

`BluetoothGattServerCallback#onCharacteristicWriteRequest` works in conjunction with `BluetoothGattServerCallback#onExecuteWrite` to reassemble fragmented data sent by the peer device. To answer your questions:

1. The parameter `preparedWrite`is true when a fragment of the incoming data is received, i.e. the data needs to be queued until more arrives. `BluetoothGattServerCallback#onExecuteWrite` will be called after the final fragment has been received and the sent charactistic value can be fully assembled.
2. If `responseNeeded` is false, don't call `BluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(BluetoothDevice, int, int, int, byte[])`.
3. Just send an empty `value`.

   Here is an example of `onCharacteristicWriteRequest`:

```
                @Override
                public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value) {
                    super.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(device, requestId, characteristic, preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value);
                    Log.d("SVC", "BluetoothGattServerCallback.onCharacteristicWriteRequest with " + value.length + " bytes");
                    if(preparedWrite) {
                        handleInputFragment(device, characteristic.getUuid(), value);
                    } else {
                        handleInputMessage(device, characteristic.getUuid(), value);
                    }
                    if(responseNeeded) {
                        Log.d("SVC", "sending response to write request for characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid());
                        if(!gattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, 0, new byte[0])) {
                            Log.e("SVC", "response to characteristic write request failed");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and of `onExecuteWrite`

```
                @Override
                public void onExecuteWrite(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, boolean execute) {
                    Log.d("SVC", "BluetoothGattServerCallback.onExecuteWrite " + (execute ? "execute" : "cancelled"));
                    super.onExecuteWrite(device, requestId, execute);
                    Iterator<InputBuffer> itr = inputBuffers.iterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext()) {
                        InputBuffer buf = itr.next();
                        if(buf.device.equals(device)) {
                            itr.remove();
                            if(execute) {
                                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                for (byte[] b : buf.bytes) {
                                    os.write(b, 0, b.length);
                                }
                                handleInputMessage(device, buf.characteristicUuid, os.toByteArray());
                            }
                        }
                    }
               }
```

The implementation of the InputBuffer mechanism is something like

```
    private class InputBuffer {
        final BluetoothDevice device;
        final UUID characteristicUuid;
        final List<byte[]> bytes;

        InputBuffer(BluetoothDevice device, UUID characteristicUuid, byte[] value) {
            this.device = device;
            this.characteristicUuid = characteristicUuid;
            this.bytes = new ArrayList<>();
            this.bytes.add(value);
        }
    }

    private List<InputBuffer> inputBuffers = new LinkedList<>();

    private void handleInputFragment(BluetoothDevice device, UUID characteristicUuid, byte[] value) {
        Log.d("SVC", "handling input Fragment");
        for(InputBuffer buf : inputBuffers) {
            if(buf.device.equals(device)) {
                buf.bytes.add(value);
                return;
            }
        }
        inputBuffers.add(new InputBuffer(device, characteristicUuid, value));
    }
```

The implementation of `handleInputMessage` is application specific.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and efforts to explain the details, I will spend time to try it myself.